# Quantiles using sample weights

Tags: r

I am trying to compute the quantiles of a vector using sample weights. One of the very few functions I have found to perform this is `Hmisc::wtd.quantile()`. The results I get seem to largely depend on the scale of the weights (i.e. mean) and I don't understand why this happens (e.g. shouldn't the 10th percentile of a variable be the same if we multiply the weights by a constant?). You can see the differences in results when the function is applied to the vectors `weighted`, `small_weights` (same weights as `weighted` multiplied by 0.1) and `scaled_weights` (with mean equal to 1).

Also, none of the results matches the unweighted quantiles produced by using the sample weights `wt` as frequency weights and multiplying the number of rows for each observation accordingly using `tidyr::uncount()` (see the `duplicated_rows` tibble below).

Can someone help me understand why this happens? Is there a way to make the weighted quantiles not depend on the scale of the sample weights?

Many thanks.

```r
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyr)

weighted <- tibble::tibble(var_ = seq(0, 10),
                         wt = c(2, 0.5, 2, 0.5,
                                  2, 1, 2, 0.5,
                                  2, 0.5, 2))

duplicated_rows <- tidyr::uncount(weighted, wt*2)

small_weights <- tibble::tibble(var_ = seq(0, 10),
                                wt = c(2, 0.5, 2, 0.5,
                                       2, 1, 2, 0.5,
                                       2, 0.5, 2)*0.1)

scaled_weights <- weighted
scaled_weights$wt <- weighted$wt/mean(weighted$wt)


quantile(duplicated_rows[["var_"]], probs = seq(0,1, 0.1))
#>   0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
#>  0.0  0.0  2.0  2.7  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.3  8.0 10.0 10.0

Hmisc::wtd.quantile(weighted[["var_"]], weighted[["wt"]], probs = seq(0,1, 0.1))
#>   0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
#>  0.0  0.8  2.0  3.2  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.6  8.2  9.6 10.0

Hmisc::wtd.quantile(small_weights[["var_"]], small_weights[["wt"]], probs = seq(0,1, 0.1))
#>   0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
#>  6.0  6.2  6.4  6.6  6.8  7.0  7.2  7.4  7.6  7.8  8.0

Hmisc::wtd.quantile(scaled_weights[["var_"]], scaled_weights[["wt"]], probs = seq(0,1, 0.1))
#>   0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
#>    0    2    2    4    4    6    6    8    8   10   10

Hmisc::wtd.quantile(weighted[["var_"]], weighted[["wt"]], probs = seq(0,1, 0.1), type = "(i-1)/(n-1)")
#>    0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
#>  0.00  0.80  1.65  3.10  3.80  5.00  5.70  7.15  7.85  9.30 10.00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I suspect that in the body of `Hmisc::wtd.quantile()`, the scaling value impacts the `low` and `high` values for `xout`, used by the `approx()` function in its calculation of `allq`.  When `weighted$wt` is unscaled, then the penultimate value of `low` is `13` and the penultimate value of `high` is `14`; these yield an interpolation of `9` (ie. `ceiling((13 + 14)/(2 * 15))`) for the corresponding values in `allq`. However, when `weighted$wt` is scaled by `2`, then `low` has a value of `27` and `high` a value of `28`; these yield an interpolation of `10` (ie. `ceiling((27 + 28)/(2 * 30))`).

Comment: In short, the root cause seems to be rounding error in the calculations made by `Hmisc::wtd.quantile()`.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, scaling by `2` gives the same result as scaling by `8`; and scaling by `3` gives the same result as scaling by `9`. But scaling by `6` gives us the same result as scaling by `2` or by `36`. So when scaling by an integer, I think all **it boils down to the [*parity*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parity.html) of the [Least Prime Factor (LPF)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html)** (here `2` or `3`) **of the scaling value, and its impact on rounding error**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `normwt = TRUE` argument is needed:

> If weights are frequency weights, then `normwt` should be `FALSE`, and if weights are normalization (aka reliability) weights, then `normwt` should be `TRUE`.

```
Hmisc::wtd.quantile(weighted[["var_"]], weighted[["wt"]], probs = seq(0,1, 0.1),normwt=T)
  0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
   0    2    2    4    4    6    6    8    8   10   10 

Hmisc::wtd.quantile(small_weights[["var_"]], small_weights[["wt"]], probs = seq(0,1, 0.1),normwt=T)
  0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
   0    2    2    4    4    6    6    8    8   10   10 

Hmisc::wtd.quantile(scaled_weights[["var_"]], scaled_weights[["wt"]], probs = seq(0,1, 0.1),normwt=T)
  0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
   0    2    2    4    4    6    6    8    8   10   10
```